# How do I do a string replace in all PHP files recursively on Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, find-and-replace, string-manipulation

I have a function name that was misspelled, and I want to change it. The function is called in many places of the project.

How can I do this with a Linux command on [SUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUSE_Linux_distributions)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of `find`, `xargs` and `sed`:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.php" | xargs sed -i 's/\<oldfunction\>/newfunction/g'
```

Comment: careful there! Doing a s/he/him/ on my comment would break "there", and that'd be difficult to fix as simply! Take backups first, and remember sed uses regex, so you have quite a bit of leeway in how you write your parameters.

Comment: you're right, fixed.

Comment: aren't you trimming off the surrounding `< >` characters?  don't you want `s/\<oldfunction\>/\<newfunction\>/g` ?  or am i not recognizing a std RE element?

Comment: Yea, they are word boundaries, I forgot to add them but Phoshi reminded me. Without `\<` (beginning of word) and `\>` (end of word), any occurance of the first string will be replaced in the file. Example, if his function is named `len`, it will also replace the `len` in `strlen` and anywhere else len is found in each file regardless if it's a single word or part of a ward, which is not what he wants. You have to make sure you are only replacing complete words, as sed has no knowledge of "words" without them.

Comment: i thought it might be but couldn't find a quick sed-regex reference to verify.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A variant done with [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl):

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi.bak -e 's/oldfunction/newfunction/g'
```

An advantage to this is that Perl will create the backup files (with `.bak` extension) so that if you screw it up, you can revert.

(The `-print0` option to find and the `-0` option for [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) are only needed if you have any files or directories with spaces in them.)

Comment: i think the sed versions will do this too if you use `-i .bak` instead of `-i`

Comment: aha, I just RTFM and ~quack is right. sed will do this too.

Comment: I'd love to see the Python variation (I'm trying to learn it) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the same thing as John T's solution:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.php" -exec sed -i 's/\<oldfunction\>/newfunction/g' {} \;
```

I usually don't pipe out to `xargs`

EDIT: more expensive.... per comments below.

Comment: there's one difference: this runs a separate instance of the `sed` for each found file; the `xargs` version runs one instance with many arguments.

Comment: yep, more forking involved.

Comment: If your find supports it, use `+` instead of `\;` and it will reduce the number of sed processes so that it mimics xargs.

Comment: never paid attention to that... thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Supplement to the other very good suggestions already posted:  make a backup of the whole site (cp -r /var/www /var/wold) and do the editing there.  Personally I would then move the modified files under, for instance /var/www/changed and test http://www.sitename.tld/changed to make sure all the scripts work before going live.